# docker compose - container is not persisting data in mounted volume

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml for my node app and mongo db.

I have 2 NFS volumes mounted on compose file. The problem is when I run container, app container logs are not getting saved in volumes logs folder. Mongo-data volume works fine, it does persist data.

Inside Container:

```
[admin@ip-10-x-x-x bot-app]$ docker exec -it bot-app bash
root@b78428d61861:/bot# cd logs
root@b78428d61861:/bot/logs# ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 23328 Jul  8 21:08 access-bot.2021-07-08.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8145 Jul  8 21:05 bot.2021-07-08.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 Jul  8 20:59 text.txt
root@b78428d61861:/bot/logs#
```

from host:

```
[admin@ip-10-x-x-x logs]$ ls -l
total 0
[admin@ip-10-x-x-x logs]$ pwd
/mnt/chatbot-efs/logs
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: db
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-entrypoint/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
      - type: volume
        source: mongo_data
        target: /data/db
        volume:
          nocopy: true
    command: mongod
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: bot
    container_name: bot-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
      - "9093:9093"
      - "9092:9092"
    volumes: 
      - type: volume
        source: logs
        target: /logs
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for.sh","db.bot-app_default:27017","--","node", "bot.js"]
volumes: 
  mongo_data:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.10.152.15,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2"
      device: ":/mongodata"
  logs:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "addr=10.10.152.15,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2"
      device: ":/logs"
```

Here is the dockerfile for app

```
FROM node:14

# Code to install Oracle
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y alien libaio1
RUN wget https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/oracle/instantclient/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient19.3-basiclite-19.3.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN alien -i --scripts oracle-instantclient*.rpm
RUN rm -f oracle-instantclient19.3*.rpm && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /bot

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9090 4040

RUN mkdir /logs && chmod 777 /logs

CMD [ "node","bot.js" ]
```

I check to inspect of the both containers I don't see any major difference on how volumes are mounted. What am I missing here?

Comment: `target: /logs`. You are showing a list of files inside `/bot/logs` in your container, This is not the mounted directory.

Comment: Yup this is what I was missing. Thanks a lot for finding this out. I knew there was something silly, needed another set of eyes. :)